# How do I automatically set a Google Sheets cell to the current date on editing its row?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Spreadsheet that I want to automatically set the value of a "Date" cell whenever I edit a row where the date has not already been set. As far as I know the Google Sheets API and how GoogleScript works, I figure this should work, but it never even sets the debug cell! **What am I doing wrong here?**

```
/**
 * Automatically puts the current date in the first column of the edited row
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var debugCell = sheet.getCell(10,10);
  debugCell.setValue("DEBUG CELL"); // if anything works, this should show up... but it doesn't :C

  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var dateCol = 0;
  var dateCell = sheet.getCell(editedCell.getRow(), dateCol);

  debugCell.setValue(editedCell.getColumn());

  if(!dateCell.getValue() && editedCell.getColumn() != dateCol){   
    dateCell.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you did not set the triggers. In the Script editor, go to **Resources** -> **Current project's triggers**
Select your function name (in this case `onEdit`) and set the `Event` as `From Spreadsheet` -> `onEdit`

Save it and you are done.

### **Edited Solution**

Okay there is problem in your code too. I missed that earlier.

[`getCell`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell%28Integer,Integer%29) is a function of class [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and NOT class [`sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). You should use [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer%29) instead. Here is a code that should work. You can edit it as per your requirements.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var debugCell = sheet.getRange(10,10);
  debugCell.setValue("DEBUG CELL"); // if anything works, this should show up... but it doesn't :C

  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var dateCol = 1;
  var dateCell = sheet.getRange(editedCell.getRow(), dateCol);

  debugCell.setValue(editedCell.getColumn());

  if(!dateCell.getValue() && editedCell.getColumn() != dateCol){   
    dateCell.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```